# SOMA command equivalent for command line "show network-interface"

Tags: java, soap, ibm-datapower

I'm researching/implementing SOMA commands for DataPower XI52.  There are several commands that give me the status of things but I'm not finding an equivalent for "show network-interface".  Is there a SOAP command that I can run to get equivalent information?  We're interfacing with XI52 via Java and I'm trying to avoid issuing commands natively through java exec...

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the SOAP-Body:

```
<dp:request domain="default" xmlns:dp="http://www.datapower.com/schemas/management">
  <dp:get-status class="NetworkInterfaceStatus"/>
</dp:request>
```